# ImportError: No module named cStringIO

Tags: python, environment-variables, importerror

I am a python Noob and I am stuck with this particular error. I am trying to run a python script within my bash script. The error log looks like this

```
File "Alpha_Beta.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pdb
  File "C:\softs\Python\Lib\pdb.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\softs\Python\Lib\pprint.py", line 39, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cStringIO
```

This is on my ubuntu machine.

Can anyone please help me fix this bug?

By looking at the replies and the traceback I do figure out, it is probably something to do with the fact that the file was initially being used in Windows environment. Currently I am trying to compile this file on ubuntu. I hope this makes it more clear.

Also this file compiles without any problems when I run on the windows machine. Not the same with ubuntu. So I need help to figure out , how to debug this. Should I change something within the pdb module or should I look elsewhere.

Comment: "This in on my ubuntu machine.". Yet the paths in your traceback are Windows-specific. Are you sure you are running this on Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you compile python yourself?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes this is on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood No, I did not compile the python myself. It is an already existing file

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? In Python 3 `StringIO` and `cStringIO` have been replaced by the `io` module.

Comment: If you're getting tracebacks with "File "C:\softs\Python\Lib\pdb.py" in them on Ubuntu, something's gone horribly wrong.

Comment: -1 for insisting this is a. Ubuntu machine despite the obvious Windows paths in the traceback.

Comment: @rubik: the traceback ends in `pprint.py`; this is the python stdlib importing cStringIO, not his own code.

Comment: It's very likely that some module he imported modified `sys.path` to append the hardcoded paths that work on the original developer's Windows box.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The initial version of it was designed for a windows machine. When the ubuntu drive used to be shared and this file was compiled in windows environment. Now, I am porting it completely to linux.I am trying to understand how traceback works because I have no idea what it means. Its the first time I am seeing a python script

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You are right, I missed that!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I knew this wasn't a real fix. Anyway, now commenting out the pdb module is causing some other errors in the code. There definitely is an inherent problem in importing modules.Is there a way to debug this issue?

Comment: We are way beyond the SO format here; perhaps a mailinglist (http://www.python.org/about/help/) would be better suited. Your setup is majorly screwed somewhere and unscrewing this is going to take some work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running this on a Windows machine, but if this from a shared Ubuntu drive then the cStringIO extension will not import; it'll be compiled for running on Linux, not Windows.

Comment: The initial version of it was designed for a windows machine. When the ubuntu drive used to be shared and this file was compiled in windows environment. Now, I am porting it completely to linux. So what would u suggest I do to make the transition? Replace the existing modules with some linux module?

Comment: I am still extremely skeptical you are actually running this on Linux, unless you have a directory "C:\softs\Python\Lib\pdb.py". Python on Linux comes with it's own cStringIO, no need to replace anything if things are properly installed (which on ubuntu, it invariably will be).

Comment: I fixed this issue by commenting the module which was importing some C- specific libraries. Turns out that script didn't really need that module (or at least didn't throw any errors for now). Lets see if I run into issues later. Thanks anyways for directing me in the right way to debug my issue